# Windows Workflow Foundation 4 (WF4) ReHosting

Tags: windows, hosting, workflow-foundation, workflow-foundation-4

I've been looking at the possibility of ReHosting a WF4 Workflow to be used to debug running Workflows.  All the posts and samples I've seen regarding WF4 Rehosting are using a WPF application to initially Host the Workflow, and then use the WorkflowDesigner in ReHosting it.  Is there any way to Rehost a Workflow that was hosted in a non WPF application, like ASP.Net MVC?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The WorkflowDesigner is basically a big WPF control so you cannot host it in an ASP.NET application. Neither can you in a Silverlight application. If you need to expose the designer over an internet app you would have to either create your own designer or use something like terminal server/Citrix.

Comment: Is there no way to even get screen shots, like a static view of the workflows present location?

Comment: There is a CopyAsImageCommand that will let you get an image of the workflow but that is still part of the workflow designer and thus a WPF action.

Answer (score 2):

You can host the designer in the browser using a wfpbrowserapplication. Details [here](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/wfxbap/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=4668)

Comment: The selected answer is incorrect. As Flores says, you can rehost the WF designer in a WPF Browser Application (aka xbap). The main problem is this will only run on IE or on Firefox (with a plugin), but not Chrome, and there are trust/security issues. More info on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970060.aspx) and on [Ron Jacob's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rjacobs/archive/2011/08/14/how-to-create-a-custom-activity-designer-with-windows-workflow-foundation-wf4.aspx):

Answer (score 0):

I just about read in another post that WF 4 will make the hosting the designer in the application easier than it is today. I too have similar requirement that the workflow designer should be availabe to the user so that he can create his own workflows. This was reasoned in that post to the fact that the WF 4 is completely markup based and no code is involved... making it easier to host in the application....